# hibernate : binding parameter if not null

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I create a web service which check an existence of data in a table. I had two input, one input is mandatory and the other is optional.
I want to create one query  which binding the parameter `mode` if not null.
I used this query but it didn't work and I had this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01008: not all variables bound
```

query :

```
 SELECT DATE_TRAITEMENT, DATE_DEB_PERIODE, DATE_FIN_PERIODE,user_cdg,canal,motif,SUJET_CRM,MODE_generation, TRAIT_STATUS,REMARK FROM  ACM.CDG_REQUEST_OnDEMAND where   CO_ID = :coId and (MODE_GENERATION= :mode or (MODE_GENERATION is null and :mode is null))  order by DATE_TRAITEMENT asc
```

and this my DAO class :

```
  Session session = HibernateUtil.currentSession();
    SQLQuery query = null;
    org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    String sql = cdg.getMessage("REQ001");      
    query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
    query.setLong("coId", coId);    
    if(integer != null) {
    query.setInteger("mode", integer);
         }
    query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Either you update the query or you simply set `mode`, as your current query doesn't seem to have it be that optional

Comment: I want to create one query, if `mode` is not null , I bound the value else it will be binding as null

Comment: add mode in the query. If the query returns null, it will not be set. If a value is found it will be set

Comment: @Aditya How can I do it ?

Comment: Think about to switch to Criteria API for dynamic queries as it seems you are using one.